# magento using the catalog style on homepage

Tags: magento, magento-1.8

I am using magento 1.8 I have added the below on CMS hamepage

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" name="home.catalog.product.list" alias="products_homepage" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
```

the style of the home page fonts for the products is not the same as the other catalogs, and want to fix this and make it same as the other catalogs fonts. any idea what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

inspect the element using firebug or chrome.  You'll be able to see where it's getting the style from.  The block as it is on the home page may be inheriting it's style from it's new parent.